# How to avoid port error already used in web framework bottle?

Tags: python, port, bottle, web-frameworks

In Python3 I have a program to test the web framework bottle:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def index():
    return "olá pessoas"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I am running the programs inside a virtualenv, in the command line. But there is this error:

```
(live-de-python) reinaldo@reinaldo-Inspiron-5567:~/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/repo$ python3 basic_bottle.py
Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_bottle.py", line 11, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3127, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 2781, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 153, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I'm using Ubuntu. Does the error say that port 8080 is already in use? But I have no other program open

Please, does anyone know what it can be?

Comment: first, try see what file is using the port with `lsof`

Comment: Thank you. Please, how can I send the lsof result to a file? For me to look up the information

Comment: lsof > result.txt

Comment: I looked for 8080 and did not find it. Then I ran the run on the 8090. I made a new result and found the 8090

Comment: try: sudo lsof -i :8080

Comment: Thank you. It looks like something runs in java: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    1178  jvb  123u  IPv6  27674      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port 8080 is already used by an other process. You probably launched the script and forgot to end it. Check with

```
$ ps -aux | grep basic_bottle
```

Or simply change the port with `run(port=8090)`.

Comment: Thank you. This appeared with the ps -aux | grep basic_bottle: reinaldo 19909  0.0  0.0  14256   968 pts/2    S+   07:00   0:00 grep --color=auto basic_bottle